# Android smartphone as a gamepad

Tags: android, bluetooth, gamepad

Is there a way to create an app to recognize an android smartphone as a bluetooth gamepad?

Every app I found on the store is a client/server app but it's not what I need.

Comment: Bluetooth is client/server... It communicates over sockets as well

Comment: But when I connect a bluetooth gamepad, I don't have a different server for every different device. I just pair the gamepad with the smartphone and it works. Is it possibile to create an app that has the same behavior?

Comment: You'd have to write *some code* to know the "default actions" that a bluetooth device sends. Game pads typically use xinput, for example. Unfortunately, that's all I know, and your question is otherwise too broad for StackOverflow